# mysql data update through codeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

while deleting i had called this function:

```
function delete_categories($id){
    $max_rank = $this->categories_model->get_max_rank();  //for getting max rank
    $rank = $this->categories_model->get_rank_by_id($id); //for getting the current rank
    $cat_id=array();

    for($i=$rank;$i<=$max_rank;$i++){
        $cat_id[] = $this->categories_model->get_id_by_rank($i); //contains the categories id that should be updated
    }

    foreach($cat_id as $id){//categories to be updated
        $rank = $this->categories_model->get_rank_by_id($id); 
        $data['fld_rank']= $rank-1;
        $this->categories_model->update_rank($id,$data);
    }
    //$this->categories_model->delete_category($id);
}
```

all the codes are working correctly and when it reaches to update_rank($id, $data) the values are not updated as it should be.
and my update_rank() function is:

```
function update_rank($id,$data){
    $this->db->where('fld_id',$id);
    $this->db->update('tbl_categories',$data);
}
```

the variable $id and $data has correct value upto this above function but while checking the database the values are not updated correctly.some of them are updated and some of them are not update.

my tbl_categories is like this:

```
fld_id  fld_name    fld_description     fld_rank    fld_status
1       Cat1         Cat1               4             0
2       Cat2         this is cat2       1             0
4       Cat4         this is cat4       2             0
5       Cat3         this is cat 3      3             0
```

i checked the values in fire bug all the values are correct but when the update is done the fld_rank is not updated correctly please help...

Comment: do $this->db->last_query(); to see for the query generated to check if the query statement does not have any problem..

Comment: @Sudhir: i did as u described.all query are executed but the query last executed doesnot changes the value in database...can you tell me y is this so?

Comment: Run your query in a separate program like heidiSQL or phpmyadmin - it will probably be easier to debug it there.

Answer (score 0):

In your Code $id represent key of the array $cat_id. So use

foreach($cat_id as $key=>$val) Where your values will be in $val